# How would I read only the first word of each line of a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to know how I could read ONLY the FIRST WORD of each line in a text file. I tried various codes and tried altering codes but can only manage to read whole lines from a text file.
The code I used is as shown below:

```
QuizList = []
with open('Quizzes.txt','r') as f:
            for line in f:
                QuizList.append(line)
        line = QuizList[0]
        for word in line.split():
            print(word)
```

This refers to an attempt to extract only the first word from the first line. In order to repeat the process for every line i would do the following:

```
QuizList = []
with open('Quizzes.txt','r') as f:
            for line in f:
                QuizList.append(line)
capacity = len(QuizList)
capacity = capacity-1
index = 0
while index!=capacity:
    line = QuizList[index]
    for word in line.split():
        print(word)
        index = index+1
```

Comment: Your indentation seems a little wayward - could you review and ensure that it matches what you see in your code editor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) at the wrong point, try:

```
for line in f:
    QuizList.append(line.split(None, 1)[0]) # add only first word
```

Comment: The `.strip()` is redundant for a plain `str.strip` (aka `str.split(None)`) and you could always throw in a limit there  leading to `line.split(None, 1)[0]` for instance

Comment: QuizList.append(line.split(None, 1)[0]) #  this for appending to list and geting the postion of the word in the list

Comment: @EshanChattaraj ...what?

Answer (score 4):

Changed to a one-liner that's also more efficient with the strip as Jon Clements suggested in a comment.

```
with open('Quizzes.txt', 'r') as f:
    wordlist = [line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in f]
```

---

This is pretty irrelevant to your question, but just so the line.split(None, 1) doesn't confuse you, it's a bit more efficient because it only splits the line 1 time.

From the `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])` [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently,
>   splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace
>   with a None separator returns [].

`' 1  2   3  '.split()` returns `['1', '2', '3']`

and

`'  1  2   3  '.split(None, 1)` returns `['1', '2   3  ']`.

Answer (score 3):

```
with Open(filename,"r") as f:
    wordlist = [r.split()[0] for r in f]
```

Comment: `Open` is all lower case (`open`) but putting it as a list-comp inside the `with` certainly makes more sense than initialising an empty list and repeatedly `list.append`'ing

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the `str.split` and similar approaches, but for completness here's one that uses a combination of `mmap` and `re` if you needed to extract more complicated data:

```
import mmap, re

with open('quizzes.txt') as fin:
    mf = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    wordlist = re.findall('^(\w+)', mf, flags=re.M)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read one character at a time:

```
import string

QuizList = []
with open('Quizzes.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for i, c in enumerate(line):
            if c not in string.letters:
                print line[:i]
                break
```

Comment: That seems like a fairly long-winded way of doing it, and doesn't actually save `line[:i]`

Answer (score 0):

l=[]
with open ('task-1.txt', 'rt') as myfile:

```
for x in myfile:                
    l.append(x)
```

for i in l:
    print[i.split()[0] ]