# Python Automatic Text After Math/Text Remover?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible with python that for example, if I have a `.txt` with this:

```
1/50 blah blah blah
6/36 blah blah blah
```

or

```
text1/text2 blah blah blah
text3/text4 blah blah blah
```

to get this:

```
1/50
6/36
```

or

```
text1/text2
text3/text4?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Highly depends on the text itself. Add the sample of the text.

Comment: for example
`text1/text2`
`text3/text4`
`hello/pls`
`can/python`
`do/that`

and then always words behind it and i wanna remove the words behind it

here:https://throwbin.io/U62KjKt

Comment: Are you trying to only output the numerical data?

Comment: look here https://throwbin.io/U62KjKt
i wanna output the things in ``

Comment: What do you have tried so far?

Comment: i dont even know where to start lol

Comment: So you want the first "word"? Are you familiar with [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I read only the first word of each line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372086/how-would-i-read-only-the-first-word-of-each-line-of-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the examples that you've posted you can just split the string and take the first item:

```
>>> line = '1/50 blah blah blah'
>>> line.split(maxsplit=1)[0]
'1/50'
```

Applying that to a file:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        prefix = line.split(maxsplit=1)[0]
        print(prefix)
        # do whatever with the extracted field.
```

There are other ways to process the file, e.g. using the `csv` module to parse it as a CSV file. Depends on your requirements.

Comment: A slightly more efficient method for this use-case is to us `partition` instead of `split`

Comment: @Tomerikoo: only if the field separator is a fixed whitespace character, e.g. a space. It's not clear from the question, so `split()` seems to be a more flexible option here.

Comment: mmm not sure why you say that. `partition` has a `sep` argument just as `split`. Worth noting though, that unlike `split` it doesn't have a default value so the equivalent for `split()` would actually be `partition(' ')`

Comment: working great, but is there a way that for example `1 10/88` or `test test1/test` is also working so the split happens after the  /  ? thx!

Comment: @Tomerikoo: by default `split()` will work with any whitespace character (space, tab, etc.) whereas `partition()` works only with one fixed separator string. `split()` is more flexible here as we are not certain what the field separator is for the data. You are right though that `partition()` is a tiny bit quicker.

Comment: @3Block: please supply a better example: do you mean `1 10/88 blah blah blah` for example? What output do you need?

Comment: it doesnt matter for me how quick it is^^